# Adjust React Player Video height and width fit to screen

Tags: css, reactjs, react-player

I'm using react-player for a video that fits to 100% height and width. It works fine on the web browser but on the mobile almost half of the screen is left empty. How can I be able to make the height and width equal to the screen height and width.

```
<VideoPlayer
        url={coldplay}
        // controls
        loop={true}
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        playing
        muted
        className={classes.videoplayer}
        playIcon={
          <Button>
            <PlayArrowIcon className={classes.icon} sx={{ fontSize: "50px" }} />
          </Button>
        }
      />
```

Comment: Did you try `width="100vw" height="100vh"`?